# Express router and routes Node.js

Tags: node.js, routes

I get this error when I try to route my

## My code

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const app = express ();
const chatCat = require ('./app');


app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use('/', chatCat.router);



app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log('running on port:', app.get('port'));
});
```

## Error

```
throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn))
          ^
```

I tried routing but it keeps giving me errors from my express.js.

Comment: You’re plugging into the router, but you need to plug in a routing function, e.g. (a,b) => {...}

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();


 app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
 app.use(express.static('public'));
 app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

var chatCat = require('./app');
app.use('/',chatCat);

app.listen(port,function(){
    console.log("Server is running on port: "+port);
});
```

Comment: still the same error, i am wondering if its because i installed the old version of express.js

Answer (score -1):

Try creating app with this https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html it will create nice structure for your project. As for your error - it needs to be express [middleware function](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html). You can't import router from your app.js as it don`t have such property. If you want to have route described here use:

```
    app.method('/yourRoute', function(req, res, next){
       //your middleware code
    });
```

also change this:

```
   app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
     console.log('running on port:', app.get('port'));
   });
```

to this:

```
 app.listen(3000);
```

And you can change 3000 to any unused port you want

Comment: am not importing my router from app.js, am importing it from the folder call app that has a file "index.js" in it that has this code "module.exports = {
 router: require('./routes')()"

Comment: @isaacmathias this `const chatCat = require ('./app');` takes what you exported in app.js file which is located at same directory as file from which you paste your code